# MongoDB isn't installing on FreeBSD 8.2 by any way

Tags: freebsd, mongodb

Firstly I've tried to perform [step by step building](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+for+FreeBSD) of MongoDB on my vps with FreeBSD 8.2 on it. I've faced problem with the last step of building it:

```
vm3578# scons .
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 2.0.1
python version: 2 6 6 'final' 0
Checking whether the C++ compiler worksyes
Checking for C library stdc++... yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/filesystem/operations.hpp... yes
Checking for C library boost_system-mt... no
Checking for C library boost_system... yes
Checking for C library boost_thread-mt... no
Checking for C library boost_thread... yes
Checking for C library boost_filesystem-mt... no
Checking for C library boost_filesystem... yes
Checking for C library boost_program_options-mt... no
Checking for C library boost_program_options... no
can't find or link against library ['boost_program_options-mt', 'boost_program_options'] in ['/usr/local/lib']
see config.log for more information
```

But this lib is there:

```
    vm3578# ls /usr/local/lib
X11                               libdb41.so.1                      libpcreposix.so.0
apr-util-1                        libdb41_cxx.a                     libpgport.a
apr.exp                           libdb41_cxx.so                    libpgtypes.a
aprutil.exp                       libdb41_cxx.so.1                  libpgtypes.so
bindtextdomain.so                 libdb4_cxx.a                      libpgtypes.so.3
boost_program_options             libdb4_cxx.so                     libplc4.a
boost_program_options.so          libdb4_cxx.so.0                   libplc4.so
charset.alias                     libdb_cxx-4.2.so                  libplc4.so.1
compat                            libdb_cxx-4.2.so.2                libplds4.a
db42                              libdb_cxx-4.7.so                  libplds4.so
db47                              libdb_cxx-4.7.so.0                libplds4.so.1
default.sfx                       libdbus-1.a                       libpng.a
dovecot                           libdbus-1.la                      libpng.so
gcc44                             libdbus-1.so                      libpng.so.6
gettext                           libdbus-1.so.3                    libpq.a
gio                               libecpg.a                         libpq.so
icu                               libecpg.so                        libpq.so.5
libICE.a                          libecpg.so.6                      libpthread-stubs.a
libICE.la                         libecpg_compat.a                  libpthread-stubs.la
libICE.so                         libecpg_compat.so                 libpthread-stubs.so
libICE.so.6                       libecpg_compat.so.3               libpthread-stubs.so.0
libMG.so                          libexecinfo.a                     libpython2.6.a
libMG.so.2                        libexecinfo.so                    libpython2.6.so
libMGPM.so                        libexecinfo.so.1                  libpython2.6.so.1
libMGPM.so.1                      libexpat.a                        libruby-static.a
libSM.a                           libexpat.la                       libruby18-static.a
libSM.la                          libexpat.so                       libruby18.so
libSM.so                          libexpat.so.6                     libruby18.so.18
libSM.so.6                        libexslt.a                        libsasl2.a
libX11-xcb.a                      libexslt.la                       libsasl2.la
libX11-xcb.la                     libexslt.so                       libsasl2.so
libX11-xcb.so                     libexslt.so.8                     libsasl2.so.2
libX11-xcb.so.1                   libfam.a                          libsicudata.a
libX11.a                          libfam.la                         libsicui18n.a
libX11.la                         libfam.so                         libsicuio.a
libX11.so                         libfam.so.0                       libsicule.a
libX11.so.6                       libfcgi++.a                       libsiculx.a
libXau.a                          libfcgi++.la                      libsicutest.a
libXau.la                         libfcgi++.so                      libsicutu.a
libXau.so                         libfcgi++.so.0                    libsicuuc.a
libXau.so.0                       libfcgi.a                         libslang.a
libXau.so.6                       libfcgi.la                        libslang.so
libXaw.so                         libfcgi.so                        libslang.so.2
libXaw.so.6                       libfcgi.so.0                      libslang.so.2.2.3
libXaw.so.7                       libfreetype.a                     libslang.so.2.2.4
libXaw6.a                         libfreetype.la                    libsnappy.a
libXaw6.la                        libfreetype.so                    libsnappy.la
libXaw6.so                        libfreetype.so.9                  libsnappy.so
libXaw6.so.6                      libgamin-1.a                      libsnappy.so.2
libXaw7.a                         libgamin-1.la                     libsqlite3.a
libXaw7.la                        libgamin-1.so                     libsqlite3.la
libXaw7.so                        libgamin-1.so.1                   libsqlite3.so
libXaw7.so.7                      libgamin_shared.a                 libsqlite3.so.8
libXdmcp.a                        libgcrypt.a                       libt1.a
libXdmcp.la                       libgcrypt.la                      libt1.la
libXdmcp.so                       libgcrypt.so                      libt1.so
libXdmcp.so.6                     libgcrypt.so.17                   libt1.so.5
libXext.a                         libgcrypt.so.18                   libt1x.a
libXext.la                        libgdbm.a                         libt1x.la
libXext.so                        libgdbm.la                        libt1x.so
libXext.so.6                      libgdbm.so                        libt1x.so.5
libXmu.a                          libgdbm.so.3                      libtcl85.a
libXmu.la                         libgettextlib-0.18.1.so           libtcl85.so
libXmu.so                         libgettextlib.la                  libtcl85.so.1
libXmu.so.6                       libgettextlib.so                  libtclstub85.a
libXmuu.a                         libgettextpo.a                    libxcb-composite.a
libXmuu.la                        libgettextpo.la                   libxcb-composite.la
libXmuu.so                        libgettextpo.so                   libxcb-composite.so
libXmuu.so.1                      libgettextpo.so.5                 libxcb-composite.so.0
libXp.a                           libgettextsrc-0.18.1.so           libxcb-damage.a
libXp.la                          libgettextsrc.la                  libxcb-damage.la
libXp.so                          libgettextsrc.so                  libxcb-damage.so
libXp.so.6                        libgio-2.0.a                      libxcb-damage.so.0
libXpm.a                          libgio-2.0.la                     libxcb-dpms.a
libXpm.la                         libgio-2.0.so                     libxcb-dpms.la
libXpm.so                         libgio-2.0.so.0                   libxcb-dpms.so
libXpm.so.4                       libglib-2.0.a                     libxcb-dpms.so.0
libXt.a                           libglib-2.0.la                    libxcb-dri2.a
libXt.la                          libglib-2.0.so                    libxcb-dri2.la
libXt.so                          libglib-2.0.so.0                  libxcb-dri2.so
libXt.so.6                        libgmodule-2.0.a                  libxcb-dri2.so.0
libapr-1.a                        libgmodule-2.0.la                 libxcb-glx.a
libapr-1.la                       libgmodule-2.0.so                 libxcb-glx.la
libapr-1.so                       libgmodule-2.0.so.0               libxcb-glx.so
libapr-1.so.4                     libgmp.a                          libxcb-glx.so.0
libaprutil-1.a                    libgmp.la                         libxcb-randr.a
libaprutil-1.la                   libgmp.so                         libxcb-randr.la
libaprutil-1.so                   libgmp.so.10                      libxcb-randr.so
libaprutil-1.so.3                 libgmpxx.a                        libxcb-randr.so.1
libasprintf.a                     libgmpxx.la                       libxcb-record.a
libasprintf.la                    libgmpxx.so                       libxcb-record.la
libasprintf.so                    libgmpxx.so.6                     libxcb-record.so
libasprintf.so.0                  libgobject-2.0.a                  libxcb-record.so.0
libbfd.a                          libgobject-2.0.la                 libxcb-render.a
libbfd.la                         libgobject-2.0.so                 libxcb-render.la
libboost_date_time.a              libgobject-2.0.so.0               libxcb-render.so
libboost_date_time.so             libgpg-error.a                    libxcb-render.so.0
libboost_date_time.so.4           libgpg-error.la                   libxcb-res.a
libboost_filesystem.a             libgpg-error.so                   libxcb-res.la
libboost_filesystem.so            libgpg-error.so.0                 libxcb-res.so
libboost_filesystem.so.4          libgthread-2.0.a                  libxcb-res.so.0
libboost_graph.a                  libgthread-2.0.la                 libxcb-screensaver.a
libboost_graph.so                 libgthread-2.0.so                 libxcb-screensaver.la
libboost_graph.so.4               libgthread-2.0.so.0               libxcb-screensaver.so
libboost_iostreams.a              libiberty.a                       libxcb-screensaver.so.0
libboost_iostreams.so             libiconv.a                        libxcb-shape.a
libboost_iostreams.so.4           libiconv.la                       libxcb-shape.la
libboost_math_c99.a               libiconv.so                       libxcb-shape.so
libboost_math_c99.so              libiconv.so.3                     libxcb-shape.so.0
libboost_math_c99.so.4            libicudata.so                     libxcb-shm.a
libboost_math_c99f.a              libicudata.so.48                  libxcb-shm.la
libboost_math_c99f.so             libicudata.so.48.1.1              libxcb-shm.so
libboost_math_c99f.so.4           libicui18n.so                     libxcb-shm.so.0
libboost_math_tr1.a               libicui18n.so.48                  libxcb-sync.a
libboost_math_tr1.so              libicui18n.so.48.1.1              libxcb-sync.la
libboost_math_tr1.so.4            libicuio.so                       libxcb-sync.so
libboost_math_tr1f.a              libicuio.so.48                    libxcb-sync.so.0
libboost_math_tr1f.so             libicuio.so.48.1.1                libxcb-xevie.a
libboost_math_tr1f.so.4           libicule.so                       libxcb-xevie.la
libboost_prg_exec_monitor.a       libicule.so.48                    libxcb-xevie.so
libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so      libicule.so.48.1.1                libxcb-xevie.so.0
libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.4    libiculx.so                       libxcb-xf86dri.a
libboost_program_options.a        libiculx.so.48                    libxcb-xf86dri.la
libboost_program_options.so       libiculx.so.48.1.1                libxcb-xf86dri.so
libboost_program_options.so.4     libicutest.so                     libxcb-xf86dri.so.0
libboost_python.a                 libicutest.so.48                  libxcb-xfixes.a
libboost_python.so                libicutest.so.48.1.1              libxcb-xfixes.la
libboost_python.so.4              libicutu.so                       libxcb-xfixes.so
libboost_random.a                 libicutu.so.48                    libxcb-xfixes.so.0
libboost_random.so                libicutu.so.48.1.1                libxcb-xinerama.a
libboost_regex.a                  libicuuc.so                       libxcb-xinerama.la
libboost_regex.so                 libicuuc.so.48                    libxcb-xinerama.so
libboost_regex.so.4               libicuuc.so.48.1.1                libxcb-xinerama.so.0
libboost_serialization.a          libidn.a                          libxcb-xinput.a
libboost_serialization.so         libidn.la                         libxcb-xinput.la
libboost_serialization.so.4       libidn.so.17                      libxcb-xinput.so
libboost_signals.a                libintl.a                         libxcb-xinput.so.0
libboost_signals.so               libintl.la                        libxcb-xprint.a
libboost_signals.so.4             libintl.so                        libxcb-xprint.la
libboost_system.a                 libintl.so.9                      libxcb-xprint.so
libboost_system.so                libjpeg.a                         libxcb-xprint.so.0
libboost_system.so.4              libjpeg.la                        libxcb-xtest.a
libboost_test_exec_monitor.a      libjpeg.so                        libxcb-xtest.la
libboost_thread.a                 libjpeg.so.11                     libxcb-xtest.so
libboost_thread.so                libjs.so                          libxcb-xtest.so.0
libboost_thread.so.4              libjs.so.1                        libxcb-xv.a
libboost_unit_test_framework.a    libltdl.a                         libxcb-xv.la
libboost_unit_test_framework.so   libltdl.la                        libxcb-xv.so
libboost_unit_test_framework.so.4 libltdl.so                        libxcb-xv.so.0
libboost_wave.a                   libltdl.so.7                      libxcb-xvmc.a
libboost_wave.so                  liblzma.a                         libxcb-xvmc.la
libboost_wave.so.4                liblzma.la                        libxcb-xvmc.so
libboost_wserialization.a         liblzma.so                        libxcb-xvmc.so.0
libboost_wserialization.so        liblzma.so.0                      libxcb.a
libboost_wserialization.so.4      libmcrypt                         libxcb.la
libbz2.a                          libmcrypt.a                       libxcb.so
libbz2.so                         libmcrypt.la                      libxcb.so.2
libbz2.so.1                       libmcrypt.so                      libxml2.a
libc-client4.a                    libmcrypt.so.8                    libxml2.la
libc-client4.so                   libmhash.a                        libxml2.so
libc-client4.so.9                 libmhash.so                       libxml2.so.5
libcharset.a                      libmhash.so.2                     libxslt-plugins
libcharset.la                     libmpfr.a                         libxslt.a
libcharset.so                     libmpfr.la                        libxslt.la
libcharset.so.1                   libmpfr.so                        libxslt.so
libcheck.a                        libmpfr.so.4                      libxslt.so.2
libcheck.la                       libnspr4.a                        mysql
libcheck.so                       libnspr4.so                       perl5
libcheck.so.0                     libnspr4.so.1                     php
libcurl.a                         libopcodes.a                      postgresql
libcurl.la                        libopcodes.la                     proftpd
libcurl.so                        libpcre.a                         python2.6
libcurl.so.6                      libpcre.la                        ruby
libdb-4.2.so                      libpcre.so                        rvm
libdb-4.2.so.2                    libpcre.so.0                      sasl2
libdb-4.7.so                      libpcrecpp.a                      scons-2.0.1
libdb-4.7.so.0                    libpcrecpp.la                     slang
libdb4.a                          libpcrecpp.so                     tcl8
libdb4.so                         libpcrecpp.so.0                   tcl8.5
libdb4.so.0                       libpcreposix.a                    xemacs
libdb41.a                         libpcreposix.la                   zsh
libdb41.so                        libpcreposix.so
```

boost_program_options and boost_program_options.so are the symlincs, with which i've tried to fix the problem. **So, is there a way to link them?**

Installation from ports is facing another problem when it's crushing after `make install`:

```
sinksource.o client/gridfs.o tools/tool.o tools/dump.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpcrecpp -ljs -lstdc++ -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options-mt -lexecinfo -lexecinfo -lexecinfo
/usr/local/bin/ld: db/matcher.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pcre_config'
/usr/local/bin/ld: note: 'pcre_config' is defined in DSO /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [mongodump] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
*** Error code 2

Stop in /usr/ports/databases/mongodb.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/databases/mongodb.
```

**Any idea how to add 'pcre_config' to the linker command line?**

As well, I've also tried the `pkg_add -r mongodb` installation, it went well, installed all the dependencies, but when I'm trying to run `mongod` command to start it, it just fails without any backtrace:

```
~ mongod 
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sun Jan 15 21:52:33 terminate() called, printing stack:
Sun Jan 15 21:52:33 Got signal: 6 (Abort trap: 6).

Sun Jan 15 21:52:33 Backtrace:
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a new or old VM? Looks like your libraries and includes are out of sync, which can happen over time with many installations/upgrades/etc.

Comment: old one, yup. is there any common way to sync them?

Comment: `make -C /usr/ports/databases/mongodb install`

Comment: it results with the same `/usr/local/bin/ld: db/matcher.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pcre_config'` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to install from the ports (/usr/ports/databases/mongodb) - there is a patch for **scons** there.

MongoDB (2.0.2) is working for me without any problems on 8.2

I can send you compiled libraries if you want :)

Comment: You mean to run `scons` command from /usr/ports/databases/mongodb? I've tried, but it gives me `scons: *** No SConstruct file found.`. I've tried `scons -f files/patch-SConstruct`, but it results with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`